# Cannot find module '@pages' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I created a React TypeScript app using Vite template.

And I'm gonna use `import { Home } from "@pages";` in `App.tsx`

I know possible solutions are:

- setting up paths in `tsconfig.ts` like this

  ```
  "baseUrl": "./src",
  "paths": {
      "@layout": ["layout/*"],
      "@pages": ["pages/*"]
  }
  ```
- setting up aliases in `vite.config.ts` like this

  ```
  resolve: {
      alias: {
          "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
          "@layout": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/layout"),
          "@pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/pages"),
      },
  },
  ```

The question is do I have to do both of them?

And though I setup this, I keep seeing typescript issue `Cannot find module '@pages' or its corresponding type declarations.` in the line `import { Home } from "@pages";`

How to fix this issue?

The structure of `pages/` folder is

```
$ ls -Rlh src/pages/
src/pages/:
total 1.0K
drwxr-xr-x 1 User 197121  0 May  9 21:57 Home/
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 24 May  9 21:58 index.ts

src/pages/Home:
total 2.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121 210 May  9 22:39 Home.tsx
-rw-r--r-- 1 User 197121  24 May  9 21:58 index.ts
```

The content of `pages/index.ts` is:

```
export * from "./Home";
```

Answer (score 0):

> do I have to do both of them?

Yes, as described in tsconfig docs of [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) option:

> Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by `tsc`, so `paths` should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling.

---

> I keep seeing typescript issue `Cannot find module '@pages' or its corresponding type declarations.` in the line `import { Home } from "@pages";`

Hard to tell without seeing the file structure of your `pages/` folder and your exact `tsconfig.json` configuration, but most probably it is because there is no `index.ts` file or `package.json` file with `main` field in that folder.

See also the [Node module resolution strategy](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node).

Comment: thanks for your answer. updated the question with the file structure of my `pages/` folder as well as `index.ts` content